# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2014

Database project build failed.  Error Details:

> Error:  MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>       File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

I also go through this answer on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891270/database-project-deploy-fails-in-visual-studio-2013). Also Download SQL Server Data Tools 12.0.41012.0, but still facing this error. Need assistance to build database so that I may publish my Database on Azure.

Regards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uncheck "Enable extended...". It will be removed in next version of VS. (Click on link 'More Information' next to it.)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me also and just fixed. I update ssdt from the link i get from Visual studio notification center and restart VS as administrator then it works fine.
-Janak