# deploy azure database (using SSDT) with Visual studio online

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools, continuous-deployment, azure-devops

We want to deploy Azure database which is in git source control in Visual Studio Online (VSO) to be deployed to the Azure Database. The script is in SSDT which I can deploy using my local Visual Studio IDE locally.

When I try to publish the database using VSO it throws following:

```
    ....publish.sql (0, 0)
Unable to connect to target server.
```

Our VSO build definition looks as below.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Have you opened the firewall to allow access from vso?

Comment: You should accept the answer from Cpt. Monac, that did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a similar thread, it turned out that the problem was the **SQL server password not being saved**. The poster did the following to resolve:

1. Server Explorer
2. Right click connection > Modify connection
3. Tick Save Password
4. Advanced..
5. Security Section - Enter password here
6. OK
7. Test connection - good
8. Re-run publish from the relevant DatabaseDeploy.publish xml file

Source post here for reference: [Database project deploy fails in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891270/database-project-deploy-fails-in-visual-studio-2013)